# nestjs-swagger - issue in generating client code with generics

Tags: typescript, nestjs, openapi-generator, nestjs-swagger

I have a nestjs project in which I am using nestjs-swagger for generating open API spec. I am using that to auto-generate client code for typescript-axios. The issue is that the client code is not generating generics properly. In the attached github code, I want the return type of `findAll` API to be `AxiosPromise<PaginatedResponseOfCreateCatDto>` but it is generating `AxiosPromise<PaginatedDto & object>>` as return type.

This same thing is explained in nestjs docs here: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/operations#advanced-generic-apiresponse. I have reproduced exact same steps in https://github.com/garvit14/nest/tree/issue-with-generics-when-generating-client/sample/11-swagger but it is not working.

I am using https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator for generating `typescript-axios` client. Command: `openapi-generator-cli generate -g typescript-axios  -i specFile.json -o .`. In the linked github repo I have added the code for generated client also: https://github.com/garvit14/nest/tree/issue-with-generics-when-generating-client/sample/11-swagger/src/genererated-client. I have tried this on node 10.24.1 and 12.22.6. Is there any way I can solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any update on it? I am facing the same issue